# The program "[2952] backgroundTaskHost.exe" has exited with the code 1 (0x1)

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, windows-10-universal, background-task

I already googled it, but haven't found anything.
The console is showing:

```
The program "[2952] backgroundTaskHost.exe" has exited with the code 1 (0x1)
```

The MainProject got the reference to the Backgroundtask. The task exits while it awaits the fileIO reader.

```
StorageFile sampleFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("Klasse.txt");
Stufe = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(sampleFile);
```

Before I already called another FileIO Reader, but the task didn't exits

```
StorageFile sampleFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("Facher.txt");
Fach = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(sampleFile);
```

All in all:

```
namespace BackgroundTask
{
    public sealed class BackgroundTask : IBackgroundTask
    {
        string Stufe = "";
        string Fach = "";

        BackgroundTaskDeferral _deferral;
        public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
        {
            _deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();
            StorageFolder storageFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

            //GetFächer
            try
            {
                StorageFile sampleFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("Facher.txt");
                Fach = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(sampleFile);
            }
            catch (Exception e) { }

            //GetStufe
            try
            {
                StorageFile sampleFile = await storageFolder.GetFileAsync("Klasse.txt");
                Stufe = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(sampleFile);
            }
            catch (Exception e) { Debug.WriteLine(e); }
            _deferral.Complete();

           [...]
        }
}
```

Comment: Why are you getting multiple deferrals? I think you should get the one after at begin of *Run* and complete at the end. If you call complete in the middle of your task, maybe OS treats it as completed and releases the resources. Have you tried that?

Comment: oh, sry. This was just an attempt to fix the error

Comment: Fixed it by putting it at the very end. Before it was after the await statement but now at the very end. Thx

Answer (score 0):

I had to put the complete tag at the very end. Now it works